# Put switch inside action bar on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm working on a project where I am currently trying to put a switch inside the applications action bar (as in the wi-fi settings : http://tinypic.com/r/2l8vt35/6 )

How can this be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `android:actionLayout` to your `<item>` in your menu XML resource, pointing to a layout XML resource that has your `Switch`. Then, use `getActionView()` on the `MenuItem` to register listeners on changes in the switch.

Note that `Switch` only works on API Level 14 and higher.

Comment: How should the xml resource be refeered to? Also, can I "reach" this switch checked state from all parts of the activity or just the menu pary?

Comment: @SweSnow: "How should the xml resource be refeered to?" -- I am sorry, but I do not understand the question. "Also, can I "reach" this switch checked state from all parts of the activity or just the menu pary?" -- the `Switch` is a widget. You can "reach" it from wherever you store the `Switch` object. If you put it in a data member of your activity, then your activity can get your `Switch`. Here is a sample project that puts a custom layout in the action bar: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemo

Comment: The first part was about exactly how the xmk should be written. This might exolain: android:actionLayout="What text goes here". Also you said it should be "pointing to a layout xml resource" so should I just tell it android:actionLayout="@id/main" and in that case, can my main.xml layout contain something else then the switch?

Comment: @SweSnow: `android:actionLayout="@layout/whatever_you_want_to_call_your_layout_that_contains_the_switch"`

Comment: CommonsWare, your comment is not correct. Switch was introduced with Android 4.0 (API Level 14) !

Comment: @AndiKrusch: Ah, you are correct. `Switch` existed in API Level 11, but was not part of the public API. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Here is a clean backported Switch View that works back to API 7: https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the example project illustrating how to work with custom ActionBar views. It was very helpful!