# Custom widget (Switch) not appearing in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-xml, android-menu

I want to add a toggle switch to my action bar, however it does not seem to appear. 
This is what I get as my screen
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1o-MgL-CQBFbml4VWZRdlptUWM/view?usp=sharing

I followed another post of the fourms to get the code -- [How to add a switch to android action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107031/how-to-add-a-switch-to-android-action-bar)
Tried all the suggested methods but am currently using Ezequiel's

This is my code

menu_main

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.json.example.myapplication.MainActivity" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/switchId"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

switch_layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity that inflates menu

```
 package com.json.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Why is the switch not appearing, Am I simply mistyping something (if so what) or is there an error in the guide I am reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
```

to

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
```

Comment: Okay that works. Is it just because I am using appcompat that I was having this problem? Also thanks so much I literally spent 3 hours trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.